# SAO Kirito immortal in episodes 6 and 8?

Tags: sword-art-online

An Immortal object badge is shown in direct relation to Kirito's actions. What are these badges referring to? Was Kirito immortal?

Comment: i don't remember exactly what was in those episode but i assume it was referring to whatever he struck being an immortal object. ie it can't be destroyed

Comment: Pretty sure that includes that one time he punched a wall and the immortal object tag popped up

Comment: This occured twice: When Kirito fought a glitch in the game to get Yui, and when Kirito attacked Heathcliffe who was actually.... In both of those cases he went against rules that the game had in place. He himself was never immortal and actually almost died in both encounters.

Answer (score 9):

You're likely thinking of the [Immortal Objects](http://swordartonline.wikia.com/wiki/Sword_Art_Online#Physical_Surroundings) which Kirito (and other characters) have been known to strike at.

> In Sword Art Online, physical surroundings such as walls, buildings, monuments, and major features are considered "Immortal Objects". An error beep and a notification will sound if immortal physical objects are struck, even if by accident.

This doesn't change the state of the player's mortality - they are very much mortal - it only informs of the state of the object they want to interact with.  If it's an Immortal Object, it can't take any damage, so striking it (regardless of intent) will not cause harm to it.

Comment: then when Kirito hit Kayaba , he got notification?

Comment: Kayaba set himself up, so that his health couldn't go below half. When it finally did hit the half-way point, it displayed him as being "Immortal".